# What happens when $$[object name] is declared?

Tags: php, variable-variables

I was trying to debug a PHP script when I came across a declaration like:

```
$cart = new form;
$$cart = $cart->function();
```

What is  `$$cart`?

Answer (score 1):

What PHP does when you declare `$$cart`, is try to get the string value of the `$cart` object, and use that as the name for this variable variable. This means it'd have to call the [`__toString()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring) magic method of its class.

If there is no `__toString()` method in the class, this will cause a catchable fatal error:

> **Catchable fatal error:** Object of class MyClass could not be converted to string...

Otherwise, the name of the `$$cart` variable variable is the string value of the object as returned by that magic method.

An example with the `__toString()` magic method implemented (different classes/names but similar to your example calling code):

```
class MyClass {
    public function __toString() {
        return 'foo';
    }
    public function some_method() {
        return 'bar';
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass();
$$obj = $obj->some_method();

echo (string) $obj, "\n"; // foo
echo $$obj; // bar
```

Answer (score 0):

the double $ is used for a variable variable.

essentially what this entails is the second $ along with the word is a variable the value of which is used for the name of the first $

i.e.-

```
$first  = "second";

$second = 'Goodbye';

echo $$first; // Goodbye
```